# DNS Lookup Error when uploading to localhost (local S3 server)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

In a docker container, the `scality/s3server`-image is running. I am connecting to it with NodeJS using the `@aws-sdk/client-s3` API.

---

## The S3Client setup looks like this:

```js
const s3Client = new S3Client({
  region: undefined, // See comment below
  endpoint: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: 'accessKey1',
    secretAccessKey: 'verySecretKey1',
  },
})
```

Region `undefined`: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63607178/13013715) answer to a similar question mentions to leave the region out, but, accessing the region with `await s3Client.config.region()` still displays `eu-central-1`, which was the value I passed to the constructor in a previous version. Although I changed it to `undefined`, it does still take the old configuration. Could that be connected to the issue?

---

It was possible to successfully create a bucket (`test`) and it could be listed by running a `ListBucketsCommand` (`await s3Client.send(new ListBucketsCommand({}))`).

---

However, as mentionned in the title, uploading content or streams to the Bucket with

```js
bucketParams = {
  Bucket: 'test',
  Key: 'test.txt',
  Body: 'Test Content',
}
await s3Client.send(new PutObjectCommand(bucketParams))
```

does not work, instead I am getting a DNS resolution error (which seems odd, since I manually typed the IP-address, not `localhost`.

Anyway, here the error message:

```js
Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN test.127.0.0.1
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:72:26) {
  errno: -3001,
  code: 'EAI_AGAIN',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'test.127.0.0.1',
  '$metadata': { attempts: 1, totalRetryDelay: 0 }
}
```

---

## Do you have any idea on

- why the **region** is still **configured** and/or
- why the **DNS lookup happens** / and then fails, but only when uploading, not when retrieving metadata about the Buckets / creating the Buckets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the second question, I found a workaround:

Instead of specifying the IP-Address directly, using `endpoint: http://localhost:8000` (so using the Hostname instead of the IP-Adress) fixes the DNS lookup exception. However, there is no obvious reason on why this should happen.